# Is this probability distribution known in the literature?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

In some work I was doing I derived a probability distribution that I do not recognize. Is it a known distribution?

$\Pr(X\le x)=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}x-\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{2}}{4}}\right)^{2}\right]$

Comment: That square root reminds me of the Wigner semicircle distribution. You might try seeing if there is some nice transformation that takes you to it.

Comment: The square root in my distribution comes from a hyperbola. The x/2 term flattens the positive-x asymptote against the x-axis, and the exponential maps 0 (well, $-\delta$) to 1 (or rather, $1-\epsilon$). 

Comment: Can I assume you've already looked through the Johnson, Kotz & Balakrishnan volumes?